# How to make Full Binary Tree with 6 nodes?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I know well about Full Binary Tree and Complete Binary Tree. But unable to make Full binary tree with only 6 nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is `No`. You can't make a Full binary tree with just 6 nodes. As the definition in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) says:

> A full binary tree (sometimes referred to as a proper or plane
>   binary tree) is a tree in which every node has either 0 or 2
>   children. Another way of defining a full binary tree is a recursive
>   definition. A full binary tree is either:
>
> A single vertex.
>
> A tree whose root node has two subtrees, both of which are full binary trees.

Another interesting property I noticed is that, the number of nodes required to make a full binary tree will always be odd.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see that a full binary tree has an odd number of nodes:

Starting with the definition of a full binary tree ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees)):

> a tree in which every node has either 0 or 2 children.

This means that the total number of *child* nodes is even (0+2+2+0+...+2 is always even). There is only one node that is not a child of another, which is the root. So considering that node as well, the total becomes odd.

By consequence there is no full binary tree with 6 nodes.

Comment: That's a beautiful argument - I've never seen this before! My approach is modeled after the proof that a multiway tree with L leaves has at most 2L - 1 total nodes, which generalizes to trees with higher numbers of internal nodes, but because it's so general it doesn't allow for the same insight you had. I'm going to make a note of this for the future!

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @vivek_23's answer, this is, unfortunately, not possible. There's a beautiful theorem that says the following:

> Theorem: Any full binary tree has 2L - 1 nodes, where L is the number of leaf nodes in the tree.

The intuition behind this theorem is actually pretty simple. Imagine you take a complete binary tree and delete all the internal nodes from it. You now have a forest of L single-node full binary trees, one for each leaf. Now, add the internal nodes back one at a time. Each time you do, you'll be taking two different trees in the forest and combining them into a single tree, which decreases the number of trees in the forest by one. This means that you have to have exactly L - 1 internal nodes, since if you had any fewer you wouldn't be able to join together all the trees in the forest, and if you had any more you'd run out of trees to combine.

The fact that there are 2L - 1 total nodes in a full binary tree means that the number of nodes in a full binary tree is always odd, so you can't create a full binary tree with 6 nodes. However, you can create a full binary tree with any number of odd nodes - can you figure out how to prove that?

Hope this helps!